# How to check whether cursor focuses command palette

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using vscode, I want to use Ctrl+h as backspace in command palette.
This works well in macOS because it is default keymap.
However, when I use it in Linux, I can't use Ctrl+h as backspace.

That is why, I try to find the way to use Ctrl+h in command palette, but I couldn't.

Are there a variable to check that the cursor focuses command palette or some tricks?